# Lesshat not installed correctly

Tags: css, less, ghost-blog

I'm following the tutorial to build a ghost theme from webtuts (http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/cms-tutorials/styling-our-ghost-theme-with-less/) , however have stumbled into a problem.

I have followed all the steps and installed grunt and bower correctly - grunt caused a problem however I used the sudo command to bypass it.

When I try and edit the layout.less and save it, while the watch command running, I get the following error:

```
 >> File "LESS/layout.less" changed.

Running "less:components" (less) task
>> FileError: 'lesshat.less' wasn't found in LESS/less_imports.less on line 2, column 1:
>> 1 //Make lesshat mixin library available
>> 2 @import 'lesshat.less';
>> 3
Warning: Error compiling LESS. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I replaced the lesshat file from one I downloaded however the error still occurs.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I was experiencing the same error. Check on the folder UberThemeStyles > bower_components > lesshat. Check if there is a lesshat.less file there.

Then go to the file less_imports.less at UberThemeStyles > LESS.

Change line 2 From

```
@import 'lesshat.less';
```

to

```
@import '../bower_components/lesshat/lesshat.less';
```

then run grunt watch again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: For whatever reason, the installation of lesshat.less was one directory lower for me. So, changing the import to the following worked for me: `@import '../bower_components/lesshat/build/lesshat.less';`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error on OSX Snow Leopard :

```
Running "less:components" (less) task
>> FileError: 'lesshat.less' wasn't found in LESS/less_imports.less on line 2, column 1:
>> 1 //Make lesshat mixin library available
>> 2 @import 'lesshat.less';
>> 3
Warning: Error compiling LESS. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What worked for me was reinstalling lesshat through this command, from the UberThemeStyles directory supplied with the tutorial :

```
bower install git://github.com/csshat/lesshat.git#~1.1.2
```

I found this below part 4, in the comments section. Does this work for you? Sorry for a late answer, I'm doing the same tutorial just now.

Comment: I don't think it worked, however thanks for your help nonetheless. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Care to explain how you fixed it? >_>

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue here on OSX, but ended up having to make a slight modification to fatbot's suggestion:

```
'../bower_components/lesshat/build/lesshat.less'
```

Changing to add the "build" directory inside of lesshat fixed it for me. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

On OS X you can also change the 48th line in Gruntfile.js from

```
'bower_components/lesshat',
```

to

```
'bower_components/lesshat/build',
```